# Preparing data from text file for Tensorflow

Tags: encoding, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding

I'm new to Tensorflow and to Python as well. For that reason I'm not quite sure if i can solve my task with predifened functions from Tensorflow or API's like numpy or scikit.

I have a text file with four colums of categorical data like locations and weekdays. Out of the first three colums i have to create input tensors for a neural network and from the fourth column a label tensor in which the column with the labels has to be encoded in the same way as the first column as data in these columns are the same.

First and fourth column have to be one-hot encoded the other ones should be binary encoded.

After 4 days of reading tutorials and examples i still have no idea, if i can solve that task with predifened functions or if i have to do the encoding from the scratch by myself.

I would be very glad to get some ideas where to look for examples how i can encode my data for tensorflow, create a tensor from the encoding and how to decode it for the presentation of results.